# Least square means with statsmodel for a mixed effect ANCOVA

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, mixed-models

I am used to mixed models under SAS and I find myself obliged to go through python from now on.
I have a database with the following effects:
- Fixed effects: Treatment, Baseline
- Random effect: patient (each patient received the two treatments)
- y: Change from Baseline

I use the following syntaxe to fit the model:

```
md = smf.mixedlm("change ~ b_l + TRT", l_1, groups=l_1["Subject"])
mdf = md.fit()
```

my question is how to get the least square means (TRT A and TRT b) with 95% confidence interval and p-value and Means Square difference wit 95% CI and p-value.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Have you looked at mdf.summary()?

Comment: Yes, It produce only summary results not means estimates

Comment: Without being an expert in LMM in python, from the (documentation)[https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/mixed_linear.html] it does seem that `mdf.summary()` should give you the desired result. Extensive examples are also available on the site. As an alternative one could use the `lme4` package in `R`, however it seems odd that you be getting the desired output.